# "Findfilters.cmake" in CMAKE_MODULE_PATH this

Tags: software-installation, windows-subsystem-for-linux, ros

I getting this error while building my project dir ,and also not able find the path for Findilters.cmake plz help me resolve this issue

CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:7 (find_package):
By not providing "Findfilters.cmake" in CMAKE_MODULE_PATH this project has
asked CMake to find a package configuration file provided by "filters", but
CMake did not find one.

Could not find a package configuration file provided by "filters" with any
of the following names:

```
filtersConfig.cmake
filters-config.cmake
```

Comment: `apt-file search filtersConfig.cmake` or the on-line search https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=focal&arch=amd64&mode=filename&searchon=contents&keywords=filtersConfig.cmake ..... I.e. please do `sudo apt install libmessage-filters-dev` from the **universe** repo.

Comment: If you have a new question/query do ask it in the form of a new question by clicking the [Ask Question button](/questions/ask).

Answer (score 1):

The question was answered in the comments by [Knud Larsen](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1393413/findfilters-cmake-in-cmake-module-path-this#comment2410365_1393413):

> `apt-file search filtersConfig.cmake` or the on-line search packages.ubuntu.com/… ..... I.e. please do `sudo apt install libmessage-filters-dev` from the **universe** repo.

So, you've to run the following commands:

```
sudo apt update && sudo add-apt-repository universe 
sudo apt install libmessage-filters-dev
```

Comment: thanks for response  i have already followed those steps but still not resolved..

Comment: @Sam The comment you posted (which you've now deleted) told that this fixed the error. As I already told you, if the error specifically mentioned in this question is fixed then this question is marked as Solved. If there are any other errors, address them in a new question.

Comment: yes i will update new question with new post. above mentioned issue resolved.Thanks for response

Comment: @Sam Meanwhile please accept this answer if it was useful. That's how this site works.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same problem and solved it using:

`sudo apt-get install ros-$ROS_DISTRO-filters`